# ImageIcon not showing in JButton

Tags: java, user-interface, imageicon

I am trying to display an icon in a JButton, but when I run the application, it just shows a blank JButton with no image inside. The path is correct and I am not getting any errors...just a blank button. I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

```
    JButton quickGuide = new JButton();
    Icon icon1 = new ImageIcon("/Project1/images/quickGuideIcon.png");
    quickGuide.setIcon(icon1);
    quickGuide.setBounds(490, 10, 50, 50);
    quickGuide.setContentAreaFilled(false);
```

Comment: What happens when you stop using setBounds(), and instead use a layout manager that respects the preferred size of the button? What is the output you get if you open a terminal, and execute the command `ls -l /Project1/images/quickGuideIcon.png`?

Comment: The path: /Project1/images/quickGuideIcon.png looks suspicious. Are you on Linux?

Comment: I'm on Mac using Eclipse. That's the path that is shown in the properties of the image in Eclipse.

Comment: Why don't you answer the question? What is the output you get if you open a terminal, and execute the command `ls -l /Project1/images/quickGuideIcon.png`?

Comment: eclipse most probably is showing the relative path to the file; Java is expecting the absolute one.... (will equal only if `Project1` is in the root, hardly possible unless you are using the root as workspace for eclipse)

Comment: @JBNizet it says no such file or directory

Comment: Which proves that your path is not correct. If you plan to package it in the jar, then you need your build process to "compile" the icon, i.e. to copy it in the same location as the .class files (in Eclipse, that means putting the image in a package of your source folder), and to use the ClassLoader to load it (i.e. use YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/yourcompany/yourapp/theimage.png")

Answer (score 1):

The Path you see in Eclipse is relative to the project's root:

[image]

**Location** tag contains the full path you need to provide.

You can also provide relative path to the location where the JVM is launched like this: `"./relative/path/to/file"`. Notice the dot in front of the relative path.

If you plan to locate the image inside the jar file use:

`new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/quickGuideIcon.png"));`

where the above location is classpath relative.

Comment: I plan on packing the image with the JAR file. On someone else's computer the location path won't be the same. Won't I have to use the path in the project folder because that is where the image will be?